# center image next to two lines of text responsively

Tags: html, css

I am trying to display an image next to two lines of text, which are centered. I have attached an example, and you will see from it that the image is to the left of the text, whereas I am trying to center the image to be on the left side of the text, and have a perfectly centered image/text.

**CSS:**

```
.center-class{
  text-align:center;
}
.righty img{
  max-width: 100px;
  float:left;
}
.vid-open{
}
```

**HMTL:**

```
<section class="">
  <div class="row pull-down">
    <div class="center-class">
      <div class="righty">
        <img src="http://www.psdgraphics.com/file/white-egg.jpg" >
        <h2>This is a header.</h2>
        <h5 class="vid-open">some text some text some text<span class="icon-right-left-01-011" ></span></h5>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

[SEE DEMO](http://codepen.io/maudulus/pen/QNNVWL)

Comment: You want the image to be centered on the page and have the text flow to the right of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply wrap the text in a div and display it `inline-block`:

```css
.center-class {
  text-align: center;
}

.righty > * {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.righty img {
  max-width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<section class="power-of-egg">
  <div class="row pull-down">
    <div class="center-class">
      <div class="righty">
        <img src="http://www.psdgraphics.com/file/white-egg.jpg">
        <div class="con">
          <h2>This is an egg.</h2>
          <h5 class="vid-open">eggs are very nutritious<span class="icon-right-left-01-011" ></span></h5>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

[Updated Codepen](http://codepen.io/Jacob-Gray/pen/yOOxVO)

Answer (score 0):

Well, this will center the entire block:

```
.center-class{
  text-align:center;
}
.righty img{
  max-width: 100px;
  float:left;
}
.vid-open{
}

.righty {
  width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you've got your image inside of a div and div is a block-level element, which means it will expand to be the full width of its parent element.

If you take the image out of the div and make the div that contains the text have:

```
  display:inline-block;
```

That div will shrink down to be only as wide as its content.

Here's your updated code:  http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LNNJRQ

Answer (score 0):

To horizontally center an `element` you can use `display: block;` and `margin: auto;`. There may be a better approach but this is the `css` I used to have the image in the center and the text to the right of it:

```
.righty > .con {
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  left: 55%;
}

.righty img {
  display: block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 100px;
}
```

**Note:** the position of the class `.con` will vary based on screen size.

Here is the updated [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JXXaBZ).