# Center a combination of text and image within a DIV

Tags: html, css, image, centering

I try to center (both horizontally and vertically) a concatenation of a text and an image within a container DIV. Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      #myBox {display:block; width:300px; height:100px;
              text-align:center; font-size:20px; line-height:500%;
              background-color:yellow;}
      #myImg {display:block; width:33.33%; height:100%;}
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="myBox">
      My text
      <img id="myImg" src="red100x100.jpg" />
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

The text is indeed centered, but the image appears in a new line.

Trying to achieve this:
 [image]

But I get this:
 [image]

EDIT:

This is similar to [center image next to two lines of text responsively](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35899786/center-image-next-to-two-lines-of-text-responsively) , but the latter also deals with effect of margin:auto, while this question does not.

Comment: set the image as the background image of the `div`. To center a div see flexbox. https://demo.agektmr.com/flexbox/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [center image next to two lines of text responsively](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35899786/center-image-next-to-two-lines-of-text-responsively) and many others found by searching SO. In addition, the `<img>` tag does not use or need a closing slash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) use of `display:inline-block;` for `#myImg`.

2) use of `vertical-align: middle;` for put text in center Vertically.

```
#myImg {
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    //Other code...
}
```

```css
#myBox {
  display:block;
  width:300px;
  height:100px;
  text-align:center;
  font-size:20px;
  background-color:yellow;
}

#myImg {
  display:inline-block;
  width:33.33%;
  height:100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div id="myBox">
  My text
  <img id="myImg" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQEnn9dYYZlciBKfaHCw17-dUgRPX3nq5_6-kV1ua-LIsId5g43uA" />
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. It works (I forgot about the 'inline' thing...)  
Also had to get rid of the text's "line-height" for better vertical alignment.

Answer (score 0):

As the image is being rendered as a block, it wraps to the next line. You can change it's display from block to inline, then set another property - vertical-align - to middle.

```
#myImg {
    display: inline;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 33.33%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Codepen - https://codepen.io/sassquad/pen/GOqQxe